# Suppose that $\chi_{\rho}(x)=w_1+w_2=\chi_\sigma(y)=v_1+v_2$, then $\{w_1, w_2\}=\{v_1, v_2\}$?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $\rho: H\rightarrow GL(2,F)$, $\sigma: K\rightarrow GL(2,F)$ be faithful representations of the finite groups $H$ and $K$ over the field $F$, sufficiently large and of charateristic not dividing $|H|$, $|K|$. Let $x\in H$, $y\in K$ and suppose that $o(x)=o(y)$ is odd, where $o(x)$ denotes the order of $x$. Let $\chi_{\rho}(x)=w_1+w_2$ and $\chi_\sigma(y)=v_1+v_2$ and suppose that $\chi_{\rho}(x)=\chi_{\sigma}(y)$, where $\chi_{\rho}$ denotes character of the representation $\rho$ of $H$. Then $\{w_1, w_2\}=\{v_1, v_2\}$? May someone give me a note for this problem? Thanks in advance!

Supplementary content：

Over $F$, every matrix $\rho(x)$ (or $\sigma(k)$) is diagonalisable, with diagonal entries $o(x)$-th roots of unity whose sum gives the character of $x$. Suppose that $\{w_1, w_2\}$ are those for $\rho(x)$ and $\{v_1, v_2\}$ those for $\sigma(y)$.

If $w$ is an $o(x)$-th root of unity, then $-w$ is not.

We can Lifting the characters to complex field $C$.

Comment: You mean to say that $w_1,w_2$ and $v_1, v_2$ are the eigenvalues, don't you? (Otherwise it's easy to see it's false, as we can decompose $w_1+w_2$ in many ways.).

Comment: Assuming that $w_i$, $v_i$ are eigenvalues, I think this is almost certainly true, but I am feeling too lazy to try and prove it. The eigenvalues all have the form $e^{i\theta}$, and proving the result seems to reduce to showing that various triginometric functions do not have repeated values in the rand $[0,2\pi)$. (I am guessing that the only solutions arise from when $w$ and $-w$ are both eigenvalues which, as you say, happens only with elements of even order.)

Answer (score 0):

Let us lift the characters to the complex field, as $w_1+w_2=v_1+v_2$, $-w$ is not an $o(x)$-th root of unity and all eigenvalues have the form $e^{i\theta}=cos\theta+isin\theta=(cos\theta,sin\theta)$, so $\{w_1, w_2\}=\{v_1, v_2\}$.

Comment: You need to show that a lift of a character to $\mathbb{C}$ is still a character.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan But that's a standard result in representation theory, and I am guessing that that is not the main purpose of the exercise. On the other hand, this is hardly a proof - it needs more detail.